# Understanding reusable apps in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am building a backend REST API using Django and Django-rest-framework for venues to sell tickets and fans to book seats. So far, I have a monolith app called 'concert', which contains all my `models.py`, `serializers.py`, and `views.py`. Each of these files now has 1000+ lines, so I'm thinking about how to split my code into smaller chunks.

I watched James Bennett's [Reusable Apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A-S0tqpPga4) talk, but I don't understand why anyone would create reusable apps.

For example, I have two models `Concert` and `ConcertTicket`. Obviously `ConcertTicket` has a ForeignKey reference to `Concert`, and so the model relationship flows in this direction. On the other hand, inside serializers, `ConcertSerializer` depends back on `ConcertTicketSerializer`, since I am using the latter as a nested serializer. It seems like if I separate this into a `concert` and `ticket` app, I will have a really weird dependency where `ticket.models` depends on `concert.models`, but `concert.serializers` depends on `ticket.serializers`.

I won't be able to share my app to the Django community because of how specialized it is to the industry, so I cannot see why anyone would try to create reusable apps at all. Is this still "best practice" with Django-rest-framework? Wouldn't it be better to maintain a  monolith app with `concert_models.py`, `concertticket_models.py`, `concert_serializers.py`, `concertticket_serializers.py`?

Answer (score 0):

Considering your example, in order to make it reusable, you could:

1. In the Tickets Application create a Ticket and an Event class. This Event would have an event type attribute so you can define different types of events, such as CONCERT.
2. The Ticket Class would have a relationship to the Event class.
3. In the Concerts Application create a Concerts class as a proxy of the Event Class, where you could define a specific manager for this concert class, and ensure the event type attribute would always be 'CONCERT'.

This way, your Ticket Application would be reusable for any type of event. Your Concert application will implement Concert specific logic and data model.

So I would say yes, there is still a case for reusable apps and it is an excelent principle when designing software.